# What is the origin of short form headlines in media/the news?

Tags: writing-style, origin-unknown, headline-english, synecdoche

Every now and then one comes across a shortened form of headlines in media, mostly the news. For example:

> [**Study: Inflation** Forcing More Americans To Choose Between **Buying Groceries, Aston Martin DBS**](https://www.theonion.com/study-inflation-forcing-more-americans-to-choose-betwe-1849060411) [emphasis mine]

The most obvious reason for this is to keep headlines simple and brief. In the example given, word "finds" is replaced by a colon, and a comma is used to substitute "and". I suspect this form of headline was born in [letterpress printing era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterpress_printing), but I've not been able to track the history of it.

What is the origin (first recorded or known usage/appearance) of short form headlines in media/the news?

*sorry for the not-quite-serious-enough example, but this is the latest one I stumbled upon.*

Comment: This topic seems too large and vague to be answered here. If you look at collections of [classic newspaper headlines](https://historydaily.org/historical-news-headlines) you'll see a lot of variation, including between publications (tabloids often favoring short headlines in massive print while the New York Times might have a 16-word title). And as well as differing between publications, it will differ between countries. I'd guess a lot of it comes from the rise of mass-market tabloids after 1900, but publications like the NYT or in the UK the Times and Telegraph have their own traditions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this topic seems too large and vague to be answered here.

Comment: For a person with knowledge about the history of printed press this would be easy-peasy. It may be traceable to a decade, even a year. I chose EL&U SE over history SE, as this is clearly a question about language, not person or event.

Comment: I'm quite clearly asking about first known / recorded appearance. Not cultural or  publication type variation.

Comment: [Headline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline) article in Wikipedia gives a hint: "The large type front page headline did not come into use until the late 19th century when increased competition between newspapers led to the use of attention-getting headlines." It narrows down the search so the news headlines can be analyzed around that time. There is an early example given: "WALL ST. LAYS AN EGG – Variety on Black Monday (1929)". I believe the short forms can be considered a "synecdoche" in some cases, as it is popular in advertising also.

Comment: @ermanen Does a similar thing happen in other languages in EU...in local newspapers here, it does.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ I believe it should happen in other languages and news headlines in other countries

Comment: You can see multiple instances of telegram-style shortening in subordinate headlines on the [front page of the _St. Paul [Minnesota] Daily Globe_](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83025287/1883-11-20/ed-1/seq-1/#words=%22war%2Bcausing%22) of November 20, 1883. For example: "The Grain Markets Confined Within a Narrow Range"; "The Ups and Downs but Slight"; "Less Doing in Provisions and Prices Somewhat Shaded"; "The Complications Among the Nations Becoming Serious"; "England Solicitous over Affairs in China"; "The Egyptian War Causing Alarm"; "A British Force to Be Kept in Egypt".